# having difficulty in finding the upload file directory

Tags: php, file-upload

I have made a `php` code to upload a file....It uploads it sucessfully...but how do i phsicaly go and check where it is...?

**NOTE : i am getting fail as output from the `move_uploaded_file ()` 
here's my code :**

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("c", "cpp", "py", "java");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

 if ( ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 100000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) 
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) 
  {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } 
else 
{
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
  if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  } 
  else 
  {
    mkdir ("./upload");
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"./upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{
echo "sucess";
}
else
{
 echo "fail";
 }


  }
}

 }
  else 
{
  echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you first check if move_uploaded_file actually able to move file or not as the directory you are moving must have write permissions otherwise move_uploaded_file fails

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

so must check like
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"./upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])
  //file moved
else
 //error

Comment: so make the directory writeable

Comment: like this mkdir("./upload", 0777, true);